# How to make android support FloatingActionButton at bottom right of the screen?

Tags: android, xml

I have added a `FloatingActionButton` to my layout inside a `RelativeLayout` as follow

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_ok" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

As you see, I have set `layout_gravity` to `bottom|right` but the place of my `FloatingActionButton` hasn't changed and it rests on top left.

How can i make my `FloatingActionButton` at bottom right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the CoordinatorLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/myFAB"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:backgroundTint="#FF0000"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:elevation="8dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/test"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Note

```
   app:layout_anchor="@id/test"
   app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
```

Comment: the CoordinatorLayout was ment to deal with those kind of situations. I would stick with it if I were in you @DäñishShärmà

Comment: i already edited my code with your answer and i upvoted your answer. One more thing i would like to ask how to change the background color of floating button. I want to make it same as my colorPrimaryDark. is it possible ?

Comment: remove `app:backgroundTint="#FF0000"` if you have it. By default, if your theme is set up correctly, you should get it

Answer (score 7):

Since you're wrapping your FloatingActionButton with a RelativeLayout, use these properties instead :

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Clearing from your code:

`android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"`

Add this line:

`app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"`

Answer (score 0):

Clearing from your code : 

 *android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"*


Add this : 

 *app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"*