# Aligning the FAB at bottom right corner

Tags: android, alignment, material-design, floating-action-button

I have this layout file. Where I'm trying to add a `FloatingActionButton`. I'm unable to place it in right bottom corner.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/action_bar_size"
            android:background="@color/myPrimaryColor"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/offline_msg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="No Internet connection"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer_menu" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The FAB part

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_create_white"
    app:elevation="3dp"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="6dp"
    app:rippleColor="@color/white" />
```

But where ever I place this in above layout, it not just happening. Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT** The `FrameLayout` will be replaced by `Fragment` at runtime

Comment: check if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31088453/how-to-make-android-support-floatingactionbutton-at-bottom-right-of-the-screen) helps

Answer (score 3):

Why you dont try to use a FrameLayout as yourparent Layout so then you can put the FAB in wherever you want as follow :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/action_bar_size"
            android:background="@color/myPrimaryColor"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/offline_msg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="No Internet connection"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer_menu" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
android:id="@+id/fab"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
android:src="@drawable/ic_create_white"
app:elevation="3dp"
app:fabSize="normal"
app:pressedTranslationZ="6dp"
app:rippleColor="@color/white" />

</FrameLayout>
```

As you see you put the FAB Above the main Layout :)

I hope this will Help you :)

Answer (score 1):

placed this after NavigationView

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fab_rootLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin_bottom"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin_right"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_shopping_cart_white_18dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/accent"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        app:rippleColor="@android:color/white"/>

</FrameLayout>
```